# java.lang.NullPointerException on PHP soap request

Tags: php, soap

I am trying soap request with authentication. Wdsl server requiring user authentication. So i used SOAP header method.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.connector.uut.cs.com.tr/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>my_user_name</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>my_password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:sendInvoice>
            <id>123456</id>
            <type>INVOICE</type>
            <invoiceNo>AAA123456001</invoiceNo>
            <data></data>
            <hash>dfa06b85d66ef786f9f091f38e09c184</hash>
            <mimeType>application/xml</mimeType>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </ser:sendInvoice>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Php soap request:

```
$auth = array(
    'Username' => 'my_user_name',
    'Password' => 'my_password',
);

$url = 'https://test.com/ws/connectorService?wsdl';

try {
    $request = new SoapClient( $url, $auth );
    $header = new SOAPHeader( $url, 'Security', $auth );
    $request->__setSoapHeaders( $header );

    $result = $request->sendInvoice();
} catch( Exception $exc ) {
    $result = $exc->getMessage();
}
```

The $result is printing "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: please post the entire error string

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException is entire error string.

Comment: print the result of `echo $exc->getTraceAsString();` put inside the `catch`

Comment: It prints {main}.

Comment: just having a quick look, your endpoint (url) seems to be pointing to a wsdl file, that does not seem quite right to me.